# Dovecot mail not showing in user's thunderbird

Tags: dovecot

A user has been off work for a week and come in today and told me that there is no email in her inbox and she should have some. 
I checked on the server in her folder '/export/mailboxes/companyname/user01/cur' and can see that there is indeed mail in there dated over the last five days which she should be able to see in her inbox but she can't (e.g. '1336741266.M815404P15122.ourmail.server.com,W=145302:2,').  
  I've sent her a couple of internal and external test emails and they arrive in her inbox. I've tried moving the mails she can't see from the 'cur' directory to the 'new' directory but still they don't show in her inbox. Any ideas how I can get the unseen emails to show in her thunderbird inbox?

Answer (score 1):

1. Have you checked the Thuderbird configuration? Have you tried logging in from her machine as a different user? Setting up accounts and all. Are you sure the machine reaches the Dovecot imap server properly?
2. Manually moving mail messages (files) from one folder to the other (cur, new) is NOT the right thing to do. Dovecot (imap) has its own logic behind each folder, each file and how things are named.
3. Do you see the old mail messages (before problems begun)? If so you can clean the Dovecot cache(s). Deleting them will not harm anything, they will be recreated.
4. A lot of other things might not be working here to give exact solutions.

Comment: D'oh and buggerations! She'd set a filter which was preventing new mail appearing in her inbox. I'll get my coat.

Answer (score 0):

User had incorrectly created a mail filter which was preventing the majority of new mail appearing in their inbox.